# Physics graphic simulations

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, computational-physics, simulations

I am interested in modeling physics using graphics simulations. I took a Python course with CS majors and one of the assignments was to simulate a planet orbiting a star. That being said, I was wondering if anyone knew of any good resources that I could learn how to do more of these types of programs. For example, gravity simulations, pendulum, waves, etc. I am familiar with Python, C++, Mathematica and MATLAB.

Comment: Check out the Blender site on StackExchange: [blender.se]

Comment: Welcome to the exciting world of simulations. Any programming environment can be used for simulations (I did my first ones in programmable Casio calculator). It is the visualization part that is more difficult. So I assume your question more specifically is "What tools can I use to visualize simulations?". Please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes, I am wondering what tools can I use to visualize simulations?

Comment: Check this out for some simulations - https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulations

Comment: Both Mathematica and Matlab have graphics so what are you asking for?  How to do the same in C++?

Comment: https://vpython.org/    Very capable 3D python library for real-time simulations and demonstrations.   Not good for realistic rendering, very good for getting your point across.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best environments for building physics simulations was Adobe Flash (now becoming unsupported by most browsers). Take a look at the following pages:

1 - Astronomy Simulations and Animations
http://astro.unl.edu/animationsLinks.html

2 - Flash Animations for Physics
https://faraday.physics.utoronto.ca/GeneralInterest/Harrison/Flash/#chaos

You'll find lots and lots of these out there. 
As a resource for building your projects, take a look at this pdf:

3 - Physics-based animation
http://www.cs.um.edu.mt/~sspi3/Physics-BasedAnimation.pdf